# Cannot login to docker repository (Nexus) via Proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, repository, nexus

I have a Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS installed and hosted docker repository created
[image]

This is running on ServerA (local IP: 192.168.0.76, VPN IP: 10.8.0.7) connected to ServerB with OpenVPN server running with public IP.

I can docker login to that repository from local subnet 192.168.0.x as well as any device that is connected to VPN subnet 10.8.0.x (tested on from several devices) and even push images there successfully.

I want to connect to that repository also from outside, so I redirected my public static IP of ServerB and port 9005 to the serverA with repository running on port 9005 using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9005 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.7:9005
```

hoping, that it should just work, but it doesn't, I'm getting an **error**:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "http://<my_public_ip>:9005/v2/": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I can't wrap my head around what is missing in this network configuration. Do I need to tell docker that repository is behind proxy? (if we consider my ServerB as proxy), or what could be an issue?

Notes:
My ServerA doesn't have a public IPv4 address, so I use this approach with ServerB (one with OpenVPN server) to expose service to outside internet, I had some web apps exposed like this and it worked.